# SNMP (net-snmp) port configuration

Tags: centos, port, snmpd

I'm setting up net-snmp on CentOS and I'm getting an issue setting up non-default port. Basically, if I set it up as 161 or port 32768 or greater, it works fine, but it doesn't work for anything between 10000 and 32767.

Any ideas what might be causing this? It's particular to one server only, and it's working fine on other similarly configured servers.

Here are the logs in `/var/log/messages`:

```
May  3 11:15:27 oninfra01 snmpd[27709]: Error opening specified endpoint "5161"
May  3 11:15:27 oninfra01 kernel: type=1400 audit(1336058127.584:57070): avc:  denied  { name_bind } for  pid=27709 comm="snmpd" src=5161 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:port_t:s0 tclass=udp_socket
May  3 11:15:27 oninfra01 kernel: type=1400 audit(1336058127.584:57071): avc:  denied  { name_bind } for  pid=27709 comm="snmpd" src=5161 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:port_t:s0 tclass=udp_socket
May  3 11:15:27 oninfra01 snmpd[27709]: Server Exiting with code 1
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work. What happens? Anything in the logs or something?

Comment: when I do 'sudo service snmpd restart', it just doesn't start. I see a start FAILED message.

Comment: Did you check the logs for any messages?

Comment: I don't see any logs in /var/log for snmpd. Is there any other place I can find logs?

Comment: Check /var/log/messages. You can also do lsof -i <port number> to see if anything else is using the port you're trying to use.

Comment: I have added logs above.

Comment: On running the command 'lsof -i 5155', I get

lsof: unknown protocol name (5155) in: -i 5155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELINUX strikes again.

Add a rule allowing it or disable selinux.

```
#getenforce

#setenforce permissive
```

This might work as far as creating a new rule for selinux, but better to disable it if you don't understand it, it will bite again.

```
# grep snmp /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp
```

Comment: [admin snmp]$ getenforce
Enforcing
[admin snmp]$ setenforce permissive
setenforce:  setenforce() failed

Comment: I don't think selinux is enabled on the server.

Comment: getenforce Enforcing <- yeah its enabled.

Comment: Great. WHERES MY UPBOAT? I'm not doing this out of the goodness of my heart you know.

Comment: UPBOAT? If by that, you mean Vote Up, I don't have that Karma=15 thing to vote you up :)

Comment: Ah, its cool, Im just joking around. I DONT CARE AT ALL. REALLY.

Answer (score 1):

One way to allow more ports for snmp in SELinux is

```
semanage port -a -t snmp_port_t -p tcp 10000-32767
semanage port -a -t snmp_port_t -p udp 10000-32767
```

(commands might take a while to run, that's normal because SELinux compiles its rulesets)

Check if it went OK:

```
semanage port -l | grep snmp
```

Comment: bash: semanage: command not found. Awesome!

Comment: yum -y install policycoreutils-python

did the trick!